# subset xts or data.frame to just one particular day every year

Tags: r, subset, quantmod

I am new to `quantmod`, it has many ways to subset dates but I need to subset to a specific day of the year, i.e, 12/24 of every year out of a data set of many years and `quantmod` does not seem to have this function. Is there a way to do that?

Example:

```
getSymbols('AMD',src='google')
```

and you get data starting from 2007 and I want to subset it to a dataframe with just

```
2007-12-24 ... 
2008-12-24 ...
2016-12-26 ...
#and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
getSymbols('AMD',src='google')
#indexmon==11 for every December and indexmday==24 for every 24th
AMD[.indexmon(AMD)==11 & .indexmday(AMD)==24]
#           AMD.Open AMD.High AMD.Low AMD.Close AMD.Volume
#2007-12-24     7.78     7.88    7.68      7.77    9193719
#2008-12-24     1.98     2.03    1.97      1.99    2912312
#2009-12-24     9.79     9.95    9.78      9.91   11331966
#2012-12-24     2.54     2.57    2.47      2.48    9625363
#2013-12-24     3.77     3.80    3.75      3.77    5798855
#2014-12-24     2.63     2.70    2.63      2.65    4624005
#2015-12-24     2.88     3.00    2.86      2.92   11900888
```

Comment: Sorry,  I only get 
"AMD.Open AMD.High AMD.Low AMD.Close AMD.Volume"   
after typing
 AMD[.indexmon(AMD)==11 & .indexmday(AMD)==24]. 
 What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah these are exactly the same columns you get with `getSymbols('AMD',src='google')`. What did you expect?

Comment: Should I not get the rows of data as shown in the example?

Comment: Oh sorry did you  mean you only get that string without any data when you run my command? On my laptop it gives the output I have posted. Which version of `quantmod` do you use? Can you please run it as you see it in my answer?

Comment: Sorry for coming across as ignorant.  I expected the rows of data after the column headings.  But typing AMD[.indexmon(AMD)==11 & .indexmday(AMD)==24] only showed the headings, but no data afterward.  So what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure. My answer works fine as you can see from the output. Edit your question with the code you are using and the way you use it.

Comment: How to you find the version of quantmod?

Comment: library(quantmod)

getSymbols('AMD',src='google')

AMD[.indexmon(AMD)==11 & .indexday(AMD)==24]

Comment: Again, please edit your **question** and add your code. Don't write in comments. Also, you need to post the output as you see it. `sessionInfo()` will tell you the version.

Comment: I found your error. It is `indexmday` not `indexday`...... You are missing an `m`. Add it and it will work.

Comment: No.  I am still new to the text editor and not able to show exactly what happened on my screen.  Basically just 3 commands: library(quantmod), getSymbols('AMD',src='google') and copied version of your code. the answer is the column heading, but no data.

Comment: You copied your code in the comments and you are missing an `m`. Did you fix that?

Comment: [1] quantmod_0.4-7 TTR_0.23-1     xts_0.9-7      zoo_1.7-13   from sessionInfo()

Comment: Yes, I fixed the m.  This is what I used -   AMD[.indexmon(AMD)==11 & .indexmday(AMD)==24] and still not working.

Comment: I am on the same version as you and it runs fine even if I copy your code. Restart R afresh and try again with my code. Otherwise, edit your question with the edit button and copy your results and code.

Comment: No, it still does not work. I may have to do some troubleshooting on why it does not work on my end. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I get the same problem as D. Chu actually.

Comment: @Sraffa I wonder what it may be. I am on Windows and it works fine. It worked fine with quantmod_0.4-7 and it still works fine with quantmod_0.4.8 which i upgraded to now.

Comment: It works in my computer if you use 23 instead of 24:`AMD[(.indexmon(AMD)==11) & (.indexmday(AMD)==23)]`. With 24 it tries to find the 25th of December and since the market is closed it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the locale then. That plays a major role depending on where you are. I have the same versions of xts and zoo and it works fine for me like this.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that's it.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sraffa. I bet the OP will find it useful

Comment: Yes, using 23 instead of 24 works.  Thank you to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to LyzandeR's answer, you could also convert the data to a tibble and use  `lubridate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols('AMD',src='google')

AMD  %>% as_tibble() %>% rownames_to_column("date") %>% 
    filter(month(date) == 12, day(date) == 24)

        date AMD.Open AMD.High AMD.Low AMD.Close AMD.Volume
       <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1 2007-12-24     7.78     7.88    7.68      7.77    9193719
2 2008-12-24     1.98     2.03    1.97      1.99    2912312
3 2009-12-24     9.79     9.95    9.78      9.91   11331966
4 2012-12-24     2.54     2.57    2.47      2.48    9625363
5 2013-12-24     3.77     3.80    3.75      3.77    5798855
6 2014-12-24     2.63     2.70    2.63      2.65    4624005
7 2015-12-24     2.88     3.00    2.86      2.92   11900888
```

Comment: That's nice too

Comment: Learning a lot.  Thanks!